# httpwebrequest proxy authentication with .net framework 3.5 return 407 error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I use this code in .net framework 3.5 project:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(ServiceUri);
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
proxy.Address = new Uri(ProxyUri);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, pass, domain);
request.Proxy = proxy;
request.Method = "POST";  
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Accept = "application/xml";
byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlRequest.ToString());
request.ContentLength = content.Length;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

The last line gives me "407 proxy authentication required". But it work if I add to config:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
```

How can I make it work without using clr 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Sun,

I resolved this problem way:

```
proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```